# copy constructor in derived class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a base class and there are few classes being derived from it. I have not written any copy constructor in the base class, it is using the default one.

So if I write this code:

```
base* b;
b = new base(*this)
```

it works fine, but if I write something like this:

```
base* b;
b = new derive(*this)
```

it gives me an error for no matching function in the derived class.

Can't I pass base class' `this` pointer to its derived class copy constructor to get it initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Derived` copy constructor takes `const Derived &` as it's argument. You can't use `const Base &` as an argument.

You are trying to do:

```
Derived *d = new Derived();
Base *b = new Base(*d); //ok, since Derived is subclass of Base

Base *b = new Based();
Derived *d = new Derived(*b); //error, since Base in not subclass of Derived
```

In order to construct `Derived` from `Base` you need to provide such constructor yourself:

```
Derived(const Base &base) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andrew, so to construct the Derived(const Base &base) {...}, I must first write a base class copy constructor? Actually I tried adding derived class override version as you suggested, but now it complains no matching function in base class :(

Comment: @Ruchi: if the default one is not sufficient - yes. But don't forget to call the base copy constructor in Derived initializer list

Comment: ok,  i have written something like in derive derive::derive(const base& b) but it is giving me error :  error: no matching function for call to base::base(), candidates are base::base(const base&) and base::base(some_arg), I have no clue whats going wrong there, i mean why erive::derive(const base& b) is trying to call base::base()??

Comment: @Ruchi: Just don't forget: derive::derive(const Base &b) : `Base(b)` {...}

Answer (score 0):

Overload the derived contructor with a version that takes the base class as parameter. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. There could be other subclasses of `base`. If the copy constructor of class `derive` would accept a `const base&`, then you could pass it an instance of another subclass of `base`. The copy constructor of class `derive` wouldn't know what to do with such an object.